# How to override default JsonSerializerSettings for one model in JSON.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

Hi I have following default setting for my service for JsonSerializer,

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
        };
```

However I have to call an external service which returns a model (foo), which require DateParseHandling as DateTime, the model is available through an external dll reference. Hence I cannot go and edit that model.

How could I achieve this from my service.

Comment: If your service returns a model where is the serialisation happening?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Okay the model uses a default JsonConverter (JsonTwinConvertor - for Azure Device Twin model), however my service has got a jsonserializersetting which parses DateTime into DateTimeOffset. Because of that I am getting invalid casting error on that line of code.